# No internet access without VPN after updating from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, 20.04, vpn, firewall

After updating to **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** internet stopped working without VPN (I use **Cloudflare WARP**)

```
righthaze@desktop  ~  ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.215.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2033ms

 ✘ righthaze@desktop  ~  ping 1.1.1.1   
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3077ms

 ✘ righthaze@desktop  ~  ping example.com
PING example.com (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- example.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1010ms
```

`ifconfig`:

```
CloudflareWARP: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1280
        inet 172.16.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.16.0.2
        inet6 fd01:5ca1:ab1e:8227:acc3:2dce:df63:6124  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3ae2:48bc:b106:86a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 92768  bytes 94782734 (94.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62660  bytes 6638358 (6.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.95  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::5:8e06:80:f76d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:85:c2:67:16:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 92436  bytes 101891366 (101.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62165  bytes 11166130 (11.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 3546  bytes 516958 (516.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3546  bytes 516958 (516.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

UFW Firewall is disabled:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

`iptables`: *(without UFW rules, full list of rules - https://pastebin.com/Ruih9u2C)*

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output from `ip route` with active VPN :

```
righthaze@desktop  ~  ip route
default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp9s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev CloudflareWARP scope link metric 1000 
192.168.100.0/24 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.95 metric 100
```

With inactive VPN:

```
 righthaze@desktop  ~  ip route           
default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp9s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
192.168.100.0/24 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.95 metric 100
```

if i connect to VPN with `warp-cli connect` all works fine

Comment: Likely your default route is wrong or missing.  Add to your question output from `ip route`.  When you connect the VPN, it changes routes and DNS which would fix this temporarily.  Alternately it could be an external firewall that the VPN bypasses.

Comment: I added output from `ip route`

Comment: The solution is to remove Cloudflare WARP, it somehow started interfering with the network after the system update